# Trouble parsing large JSON file to Pandas DataFrame in Python due to Memory Error

Tags: python, json, parsing, memory, twitter

I'm using the following Python3 code in PyCharm to parse out the user ID and tweet ID from JSON files with Twitter data. I was able to successfully create the lists, dataframes, and export the CSVs for 13 files ranging in size up to 57**MB**.

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8' , errors='ignore') as json_file:
    data = json.loads("[" + json_file.read().replace("}\n{", "},\n{") +  "]")

user_ids = []
for tweet in data:
    if 'user' in tweet.keys():
        if 'id_str' in tweet["user"].keys():
            user_ids.append(tweet["user"]["id_str"])

tweet_ids = []
for tweet in data:
    if 'id_str' in tweet.keys():
        tweet_ids.append(tweet['id_str'])

data_tuples = list(zip(user_ids, tweet_ids))

df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns = ['User ID', 'Tweet ID'])

print(df)
print('\nLength is ' + str(len(df)))
df.to_csv(outfile, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

However, when I try to apply this code on a 26**GB** JSON file of the same structure, I'm receiving the following Memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/taylo/PycharmProjects/TwitterTest/JSON_Flatten.py", line 23, in <module>
    data = json.loads("[" + json_file.read().replace("}\n{", "},\n{") +  "]")
MemoryError
```

Is there a way to read this file in parts, successively appending the parts to the outfile?

Comment: Uh...are you sure that is a valid json file you are reading?  You should not have to mess around with replacing newlines.

Comment: I have doubts about the tidyness of the file, but adjusting the code this way has worked for the 13 other files. Simply attempting to read the file without making adjustments does present errors.

Comment: @thb5018 Is there any way you can share the start and the end of the file, so that we can at least check the structure there?